# Incrementation in model's setData()

Tags: magento-1.9, database, model

I'm looking for a way to add 1 to count in the model. Something like:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('mymodule/mytable');
$model->setData(array('date'=>$myDate,'hour'=>$myTime,'count'=>'count + 1???'));
$model->save();
```

The problem is that the record might not exist yet, so I guess that I can't load the model before creating and use it like:

```
$model->setCount(($model->getCount() == null ? 1 : ($model->getCount() + 1));
```

Should I try to load the model first and then if it doesn't exist use:

```
$model->setData(array('date'=>$myDate,'hour'=>$myTime,'count'=>'1'));
```

otherwise use:

```
$model->setCount($model->getCount() + 1);
```

or there is a better way to do that? These are two db queries and in raw MySQL I could use only one (`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`) to solve my problem.

Comment: In my opinion if you want to check existence - you need firstly $model->load(333) and check via $model->getId()

Comment: @zhartaunik I know that, it's not the point of the question though

Comment: Maybe I wrote not very clear. It was answer on question "Should I try to load the model first and then ....". I think this is good way

Comment: Now I see your point. Thank you for your answer, I did it the same way myself, but there should be a slightly better method that they probably didn't implement :)

Comment: Sure you can make direct call to database to check this value. If you do not work with EAV I think it doesn't make sence (call via model or through direct sql query)